# Replace custom Keyboard Keys to appear in RichTextbox in C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox, keymapping

**Hello World!**
I am looking for a solution, during typing keys in `RichTextBox`, I want to replace some of my keyboard keys with other keys from a different language. The replacements need instant like, whenever I type **"A"**, I want **"ب"** OR my other desire Arabic Alphabet should appear in `RichTextBox`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow** community!  Please show your effort to solve this first, tell us what specific problem you're running into and follow the good practices when asking on the **StackOverflow**: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with placing my desire Urdu/Pashto strings Alphabets in the richTextBox1 when I click any of the my Key through `SendKeys.Send("ر");` in each method. It replaces the keys into strings inside a richtextBox1 While the exceptions of two strings on a single button for Capslock and Shift can be solved through

```
if (chkCapsLock.Checked == true || chkShiftLeft.Checked == true || chkShiftRight.Checked == true)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("ړ");
            chkShiftLeft.Checked = false;
            chkShiftRight.Checked = false;

        }
        else
        {
            SendKeys.Send("ر");

        }
```